# Get last entry from associated list with Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I've got a question about Spring JPA (JPQL and sorts).
Been searching my ass of for this and i can't seem to find an answer.
If there is any duplicate, please let me know. I haven't come across a question/tutorial/guide that fits my needs.

Okay so i got Spring with JPA. And i have 2 entities.
Asset and AssetStatus. An Asset could have multiple AssetStatuses, one AssetStatus belongs to an Asset.

The entities are build as following. I omitted the unneeded properties.

Asset:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_ASSET")
public class Asset implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "asset", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<AssetStatus> assetStatus;
}
```

AssetStatus:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_ASSETSTATUS")
public class AssetStatus implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomLocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomLocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    @Column(name = "timestamp", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;

    @JsonIgnore
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Asset asset;
}
```

And i got a standard AssetRepository. (Ignore the find by barcode, its an omitted property from Asset.)

```
public interface AssetRepository extends JpaRepository<Asset, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Asset> {

    Asset findOneByBarcode(String barcode);
}
```

Now i want to get all my assets, with the last AssetStatus they had. Which is defined by the timestamp in AssetStatus. Getting all assets works but i also get all AssetStatuses they have (or had). I just want the most recent.

How do i manage to do this? I tried writing a custom query with @Query. Or name a method like findLastAssetStatus() or something. All didn't work.

Is there someone who could help me figure this out? I am willing to give more information and answer any questions asked.

EDIT: I found out the query in MySQL to get the wanted result (Works in MySQL Workbench on my database):

```
SELECT * FROM T_ASSET asset JOIN T_ASSETSTATUS assetStatus WHERE asset.id = assetStatus.asset_id AND assetStatus.timestamp = (SELECT max(timestamp) FROM T_ASSETSTATUS WHERE asset_id = asset.id);
```

As i use this in my AssetRepository with @query nativequery=true (As specified below), it does not give me the wanted result. This will still give me every status with every assetStatus it has ever had.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM T_ASSET asset JOIN T_ASSETSTATUS assetStatus WHERE asset.id = assetStatus.asset_id AND assetStatus.timestamp = (SELECT max(timestamp) FROM T_ASSETSTATUS WHERE asset_id = asset.id)", nativeQuery = true)
List<Asset> findAssetWithlastStatus();
```

How do i write this query in JPQL? Or solve this in any other way?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers, Clemenz

Comment: It seems that you need to write a custom JPQL query for that. And possibly move from EAGER to LAZY, as eager fetch will make the whole AssetStatus collections to be loaded, well ... eagerly. :)

Comment: But, when i view a single Asset entity i want the whole list to be loaded (automatically) because that's where i want to view the whole history.
Only in the overview (A table) of multiple Assets i want to view the last status it has. I wanted to use a DTO. But in the REST controller, the list of assets is put in a Page<Asset> object/list. (As we use pagination). So i don't know how to do that either. Thanks for the reply though.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Hibernate filters](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch19.html). Write a filter which will filter out the old statuses and enable it in the sessions in which you want it to be applied.